# How to select json array from mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have such json array in MySql

```
[{  "to": "0xACA7A6819ebc5135D1Be4D9952C1219ad6a3182f", 
  "from": "0xF6b023e576E86067e9604ee31215873E4495C06f"}]
```

I need simple action, just get all array!

```
 // This not work
 SELECT deposit FROM users WHERE wallet = 0X...
```

Comment: can you please provide mysql version.? also datatype of column

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'like' keyword.

ex :

```
"SELECT deposit FROM users WHERE wallet like '%0xACA7A6819ebc5135D1Be4D9952C1219ad6a3182f%';
```

statement above should able to select all the record where wallet column contain string above.

Note : add the percent sign indicate it's a wildcard search

Comment: Not help
= or like return the same result

RowDataPacket { deposit: 'deposit' }

Comment: Sorry my mistake

this not work

SELECT ? FROM users WHERE wallet like ?

need do this

SELECT" + columnName + "FROM users WHERE wallet like ?

Comment: Hi @РусланМиров ,I have edited the answer again.To add percent sign to indicate wildcard search might help u to search out the record.